I want to write an RISC-V assembly code that removes zeros from the given array and stores in the same exact memory address
I want to remove zero numbers from the given array that contains a sequence of numbers terminated with last element -1.  For example:
arr2: .word 0 0 2 0 0 -1 ====> arr: .word 2 -1
arr: .word 0 3 0 0 3 0 3 0 -1 ====> arr: .word 3 3 3 -1

I tried writing this code:
.data
arr: .word 0 0 2 0 0 -1
.macro print_int (%x)
li a7, 1
mv a0, %x
ecall
.end_macro
.text
MAIN: #load array address to t0 to start and inizialize t3 to check if element is -1
li t3, -1
la t0, arr
loop:
# load first element of array and if it is zero replace current 0 with next array element and  
# move to check next element if the element is -1 go to print and print the array
lw t1, 0(t0)
beq t1, t3 print
addi t0, t0, 4
bnez t1, loop
lw t2, 4(t0)
mv t1, t2
sw t1, 0(t0)
j loop
print: #print the modified array
la t1, arr
printloop:
lw t2, 0(t1)
print_int (t2)
addi t1, t1, 4
beq t2, t3, exit
j printloop


exit:
li a7, 10
ecall

Edit: I wrote C++ code for this:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int arr[6] = {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, -1};
  int arr_temp[6];
  int final_index = 0;
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
      arr_temp[j++] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    if (arr_temp[i] == -1) {
      final_index = i + 1;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < final_index; ++i) {
    arr[i] = arr_temp[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < final_index; ++i) {
    std::cout << " " << arr[i] << " ";
  }
}

and i get this output in the console:
0220-1

instead of this:
2-1

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Do you have a working version in C or other language?  If so, you can compare single step line-by-line debugging to see where the assembly one goes wrong.  If not, then make one, as developing an algorithm in C or Java is much easier than doing same in assembly, and taking a working algorithm to assembly is also pretty simple, both together are easier than creating an algorithm in assembly from scratch when you don't know assembly or the algorithm as yet.

Otherwise, single step and see where it does something unexpected or something is missing, compare with your mental model of how it should work.  You have to ask yourself why does it print the first 0 which is unexpected.  Inspect the data array during single step debugging of the first loop.

@ErikEidt Thanks, I wrote c++ code for this but since I don't know vectors yet i used array and left some dangling spots after -1 in the first array. but now I got a better vision on how to write Riscv code, I will try to rewrite the code now. thanks a lot!

The usual algorithm to filter an array is srcp = dstp = array; and always increment the source pointer, but skip the store and increment the destination pointer if the element is one you want to discard.  tmp = *src++; if(keep tmp) *dst++ = tmp;

I think I have solved the problem thanks to the comments, i tried to write c++ code and then write that code in assembly and i came to this code and it finally worked as i wanted:
.data
arr: .word 0 0 2 0 0 -1
arrtemp: .space 24
msg: .string " "
.macro print_str (%x)
li a7, 4
la a0, %x
ecall
.end_macro
.macro print_int (%x)
li a7, 1
mv a0, %x
ecall
.end_macro
.text
MAIN:
li t3, -1
la t0, arr # load source array
la t1, arrtemp # load auxilary array
li t4, 6 # array size
li s0, 0


loop: # add non zero elements from source array to auxilary array 
lw t5, 0(t0) 
beq s0, t4, replace
beqz t5, addjump
lw t6, 0(t1)
mv t6, t5
sw t6, 0(t1)
addi t0,t0,4
addi s0, s0, 1
addi t1, t1, 4
j loop
addjump:
addi t0, t0, 4
addi s0, s0, 1
j loop



replace: # overwrite source array with auxilary array
la t0, arr
la t1, arrtemp
li t2, -1
replaceloop:
lw s0, 0(t1)
sw s0, 0(t0)
addi t1, t1, 4
addi t0, t0, 4
beq t2, s0, print
j replaceloop


print: # print modified source array
li t3, -1
la t0, arr2
printloop:
lw t1, 0(t0)
print_int(t1)
addi t0, t0, 4
beq t1, t3, exit
j printloop


exit:
li a7, 10
ecall


This is possible with one loop that makes one pass over the array, and no additional storage.  (Well, 2 loops if separate the printing.)  If read and write positions start equal so you're loading and storing the same element back to where it came from, which is fine.  The read position will get ahead at the first dropped element, where the destination pointer doesn't increment.  It's good that you solved your own problem, but future readers should be aware that this isn't the simplest or most efficient way to do it.  It needs an unknown amount of extra storage.
